# PlayGamesPlatform not returning displayname

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-play-services, real-time, multiplayer

I am trying to get the display name of myself and other users in my game, that I am creating in Unity 3d. I have implemented Google Play Services for a real time multiplayer game. I am using `PlayGames.Instance.RealTime.GetSelf().DisplayName` and all I get is an empty string. The same thing happens when trying to get other players' display names by enumerating through connected players like so:

`public string GetPlayerUsername(string participantId)
{
        string username = "";
        foreach (var player in PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.RealTime.GetConnectedParticipants())
        {
            if (player.ParticipantId == participantId)
                username = player.DisplayName;
        }
        return username;
}`

Answer (score 0):

Google recently changed the test procedure. 
1. Make sure you uploaded the apk to beta.
2. You enabled open or closed beta testing properly.
3. In the play games section in the dev console you enabled beta testing as well.

Full details can be found here:
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en

Comment: Alpha should work, but I haven't tested. Tried Beta and it worked.

Comment: I wonder why alpha isn't working. I don't want to push it to beta just yet.